# Pushing from Eclipse to Openshift: Read timeout after 30,000 ms

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, git, openshift

I've been working on an Openshift web application in Eclipse, and I'm having some trouble pushing my changes. There didn't used to be any issue. It used to be that I would hit "publish to Openshift" and the following would print to the console.

```
Preparing build for deployment
Deployment id is <redacted>
Activating deployment
Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge
Starting jbossews cartridge
Found <redacted> listening port
-------------------------
Git Post-Receive Result: success
Activation status: success
Deployment completed with status: success
```

Now, the build hangs. Sometimes it'll hang after `Preparing build for deployment`, and when that happens, I can no longer access the webpage. Other times, it'll hang after `Starting jbossews cartridge`, and when that happens, I can access the webpage if I wait a few seconds.

When I check the error log, I get the following:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: <redacted>: Read timed out after 30,000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackPushConnection.doPush(BasePackPushConnection.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackPushConnection.push(BasePackPushConnection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.PushOperation.run(PushOperation.java:197)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.egit.core.EGitUtils.push(EGitUtils.java:539)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.egit.core.EGitUtils.push(EGitUtils.java:515)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.internal.core.server.OpenShiftServerPublishMethod.push(OpenShiftServerPublishMethod.java:263)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.internal.core.server.OpenShiftServerPublishMethod.access$0(OpenShiftServerPublishMethod.java:257)
    at org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.internal.core.server.OpenShiftServerPublishMethod$PublishJob.run(OpenShiftServerPublishMethod.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Read timed out after 30,000 ms
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.readTimedOut(TimeoutInputStream.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutInputStream.read(TimeoutInputStream.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.IO.readFully(IO.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PacketLineIn.readLength(PacketLineIn.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SideBandInputStream.needDataPacket(SideBandInputStream.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SideBandInputStream.read(SideBandInputStream.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackPushConnection.doPush(BasePackPushConnection.java:207)
    ... 10 more
```

I've tried going into Eclipse Preferences to increase the Debug timeout beyond 30,000 ms, but that doesn't seem to have any impact. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using a different Git client?

Answer (score 3):

For those curious, I was able to fix this issue simply by increasing the timeout within Eclipse Preferences. Go to Preferences > Team > Git and increase your remote connection timeout. I upped mine from 30 seconds to 90 seconds and now everything works fine.